# Cast from '[[String : Any]]' to unrelated type '[String : Any]' always fails in FireBase Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

Hey I'm trying to simply put the databaseList variable in the .updateChildValues(databaseList)

Code:

```
       var databaseList = [[String: Any]]()

       Database.database().reference().child(childref).child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("node").updateChildValues((databaseList as? [String: Any])!) { (error, value) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error")
                return
            } else {
                print("Success")
            }
        }
```

> Warning: Cast from '[[String : Any]]' to unrelated type '[String : Any]' always fails

Attemp number 2 Code:

```
Database.database().reference().child(childref).child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("node").updateChildValues(databaseList)
```

> Red Error: Cannot convert value of type '[[String : Any]]' to expected argument type '[AnyHashable : Any]'

**Also just to note i need the databaseList to stay a [String: Any]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just put an array of dictionaries into Firebase. What you can do, however, is to iterate through your `databaseList` object, and create a unique key under your reference to store this dictionary under.

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly declaring `databaseList` as a `[[String:Any]]` instead of a `[String: Any]`:

```
var databaseList = [[String: Any]]()
```

Change this to

```
var databaseList = [String: Any]()
```

Answer (score 0):

`[]` means an array , while `[:]` means dictionary. `[String: Any]` means a dictionary and all of its keys are string. `var databaseList = [String: Any]` you are creating an array of dictionaries. In the next attempt you are trying to cast a dictionary from a variable which is already declared as an array. so it fails.

Solution 
     `var databaseList = [String: Any] ()`